How to assign points automatically from one table to another?
I'm organising a challenge where participants get points on different categories. I'm going to assign numbers to the tables to make the understanding easier.
On table 1, I have a ranking system of sorted values from another table which has values referenced from other sheets. In this table, depending on how high the value is, the participant get points.
enter image description here
The three highest values are give 3, 2, and 1 points accordingly.
On table 2, I have a leaderbord where I wish to count all the points given to participant from all categories.
enter image description here
I can't seem to find a solution of assigning points automatically to this table.
The idea is for the points to be give to each participant automatically, as if it was a race in real time. If, eventually, one participant gets overtaken, the values of table 2 would also be updated.
